# How to extend a render DOM in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Say I have a child class extends from parent class.
Parent class renders

```
<div id="container" class="style-scope ">
    .....
    bunch of DOM.
</div>
```

In child classes, how could I render a HTML DOM like any of below examples without copy paste?

```
<div id="container" class="style-scope ">
    .....
    bunch of DOM.
    <div id="childContainer">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div id="container" class="style-scope ">
    .....
    bunch of DOM.
</div>
<div id="childContainer">
</div>
```

Comment: Check React.Portal

Answer (score 0):

Have the parent render it’s children.

```
render () {
  return (
  <>
    <div id="container" className="style-scope ">
        .....
        bunch of DOM.
    </div>
    { this.props.children }
  </>
  )
}
```

Then you can do:

```
<Parent>
  <div id=“childContainer”>...</div>
</Parent>
```

To get:

```html
    <div id="container" class="style-scope ">
        .....
        bunch of DOM.
    </div>
    <div id=“childContainer”>...</div>
```

Comment: Cool. but how to do this? The appended dom is inserted to the existing bottom?
```<div id="container" class="style-scope ">
      .....
      bunch of DOM.
      <div id="childContainer">
    </div>
</div>```

Comment: How do do what? I don't understand what you're asking that isn't already laid out in the answer.